# jquery selectors - identify each select/option value, in each Group

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to identify (alert) each select/option value, in each Group.
But I need a push...

```
<script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.js"></script>

<div  id="groupA" class="preGroups">

    <div id="section-A1">
    <input name="SRPR1"  type="text">
        <select name='ACTC' id='preAction' > 
            <option value='007'>Stolen</option> 
            <option value='008'>Tampered</option> 
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="section-A2">
    <input name="SRPR1"  type="text">
        <select name='ACTC' id='preAction' > 
            <option value='007'>Stolen</option> 
            <option value='008'>Tampered</option> 
        </select>
    </div>

</div>

<div  id="groupB" class="preGroups">

    <div id="section-B1">
    <input name="SRPR1"  type="text">
        <select name='ACTC' id='preAction' > 
            <option value='007'>Stolen</option> 
            <option value='008'>Tampered</option> 
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="section-B2">
    <input name="SRPR1"  type="text">
        <select name='ACTC' id='preAction' > 
            <option value='007'>Stolen</option> 
            <option value='008'>Tampered</option> 
        </select>
    </div>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function()
{    
        // iterate through each group in groups
        groups = $('div[id^="group"]'); 
        $.each(groups, function(key, group) {
            fnValidateGroup($(group));      
        });

        // validation for reason codes in a specific Group
        function fnValidateGroup(currentGroup){

            selects = $(currentGroup).find('select[name="ACTC"]'); 
            $.each(selects, function(key, activity) {
                // show me activity seelctec in each case
                alert($(activity).val) ;
            });
        }
});     



</script>
```

**edit **
    output should look like:

```
new Group
007
008
new Group
007
007
```

**edit **
Here is the answer I came to with your help...

```
$(document).ready(function()
{    
        // iterate through each group in groups
        groups = $('div[id^="group"]'); 
        $.each(groups, function() {
            console.log("New Group");
            fnValidateGroup(this);      
        });

        // validation for reason codes in a specific Group
        function fnValidateGroup(currentGroup){

            selects = $(currentGroup).find('select[name="ACTC"]'); 
            $.each(selects, function(key, activity) {
                // show me activity seelctec in each case
                console.log(($(activity)).val());
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: You may note the difference between the jQuery each functions, there are two of them. [This one](http://api.jquery.com/each/) iterates over jQuery objects. [And this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) one iterates over javascript objects. For your purposes the first one is easier to use since you have jQuery objects. Then you don't need to reference key,value variables. You'll see I used the first one in my answer to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work. What have you tried?

```
$("select").each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("name"));
    $(this).children("option").each(function(){
        alert($(this).html());

    });
});
```

Or if you want to alert them in pairs (wasn't sure based on your question)

```
 $("select").each(function(){
        var selectName = $(this).attr("name");
        $(this).children("option").each(function(){
            alert(selectName + " " + $(this).html());

        });
    });
```

Here's with your group validation

```
var groups = $("div[id^='group']");
groups.each(function(){
    var thisGroup = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).find("option").each(function(){
         alert(thisGroup + " " + $(this).val());

    });


});
```

Comment: looks like a solution, but I want to do additional validation by group.

Comment: What do you mean validation by group?

Comment: in the html, I break the data into "groups", with one id for each group.

Comment: Can you give an example of what your output would look like?

Comment: My example uses alert's, but I added "expected output" at the bottom of the example.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div").each(function(){

    $("select option",this).each(function(){

        alert($(this).val());

    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EPmLh/5/